# Firebase Cloud Function Works With Postman But Not From App

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have written and tested a Firebase cloud function in the emulator using Postman. I was beginning to integrate the call into my app and when testing something strange happened. The call was connecting and I was seeing the `Beginning execution of "[Function Name]"` in the logs, but then it does nothing, not even executing the log line at the top of the cloud function, and after 60 seconds it times out. I reiterate the exact same function works without issue when called from Postman.

Comment: Are you able to inspect the corresponding logs in Log Explorer? Do they provide any meaningful insights?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't realize more in depth logs existed beyond what was in the main Firebase terminal, upon closer inspection I had been setting my headers backwards, i.e. value of 'Authorization' for header of name 'Bearer ...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrectly setting the headers in my app and had my values and header titles reversed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).